# Is String a Permutation of list of strings

Tags: c++

A list of words is given and a bigger string given how can we find whether the string is a permutation of the smaller strings.

eg- `s= badactorgoodacting dict[]={'actor','bad','act','good'] FALSE`

eg- `s= badactorgoodacting dict[]={'actor','bad','acting','good'] TRUE`

The smaller words themselves don't need to be permuted. The question is whether we can find a ordering of the smaller strings such that if concatenated in that order it gives the larger string

One more constraint - some words from `dict[]` may also be left over unused

The following gives a complexity O(n2). Any other ways to do this.. so as to improve complexity or increase efficiency in general? Mostly in Java. Thanks in Advance!

```
bool strPermuteFrom(unordered_set<string> &dict, string &str, int pos)
{
  if(pos >= str.size())

    return true;

  if(dict.size() == 0)
    return false;

  for(int j = pos; j < str.size(); j++){
    string w = str.substr(pos, j - pos + 1);
    if(dict.find(w) != dict.end()){
      dict.erase(w);
      int status = strPermuteFrom(dict, str, j+1);
      dict.insert(w);
      if(status){
        if(pos > 0) str.insert(pos, " ");
        return status;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}


bool strPermute(unordered_set<string> &dict, string &str)
{
  return strPermuteFrom(dict, str, 0);
}
```

Comment: Fixed the tag for you, in the future, please pay attention to the tag(s) you use

Comment: @RC. I read "Mostly in Java" in the question, so the C++ code is probably just an example of an existing solution in the wrong language. Would be better to let the user clarify instead of switching tags.

Comment: Maybe maybe not, at the moment, there's no java in here, and if the question is how to translate this code to a more optimal java version, then it's probably too broad

Comment: The "mostly in Java" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample you give doesn't take much advantage of `unordered_set` (equivalent to Java `HashSet`'s properties); each lookup is `O(1)`, but it has to perform many lookups (for each possible prefix, for the entire length of the string). A `std::set` (Java `TreeSet`), being ordered, would allow you to find all possible prefixes at a given point in a single `O(log n)` lookup (followed by a scan from that point until you were no longer dealing with possible prefixes), rather than `stringlength` `O(1)` lookups at each recursive step.

So where this code is doing `O(stringlength * dictsize^2)` work, using a sorted set structure should reduce it to `O(dictsize log dictsize)` work. The string length doesn't matter as much, because you no longer lookup prefixes; you look up the remaining string once at each recursive step, and because it's ordered, a matching prefix will sort just before the whole string, no need to check individual substrings. Technically, backtracking would still be necessary (to handle a case where a word in the dict was a prefix of another word in the dict, e.g. `act` and `acting`), but aside from that case, you'd never need to backtrack; you'd only ever have a single hit for each recursive step, so you'd just be performing dictsize lookups, each costing `log dictsize`.